# What is the best approach for specified optical character recognition?

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, regex, ocr

I have a quite understandable request of extracting information (invoice number, invoice data, due date, total etc.) from scanned invoices (the digital format is image, not PDF), preferably in Python. The good thing is that the necessary information is more or less certain to exist on the page, and the (regexp-like) textual format of these is also tend to be consequent. The downside on the other hand is that the layout of the invoices are very diverse.

I have played with the following possible approaches:

- Use character recognition to extract pure text and later try to
  puzzle with the fragments. This method has some considerable
  problems: the quality of the OCR (at least of the implemented one in
  tesseract library) are quite mediocre and the output is hopelessly
  unstructured (practically a big pile of words), it is very difficult
  to come out any regexp or other rule even for regular phrases.
- My other approach would be to apply some kind of deep learning either to
  the raw image itself or the text pile where we leave the heavy
  lifting to the network, but in this case I'm not sure what is
  supposed to be the output? Is it some kind of a sequence to sequence
  mapping?

Very unusual task, indeed.

Comment: Search terms: "Document layout analysis" followed by "document image information extraction".

Comment: @Hendrik What do you mean by the layout is very 'diverse'? I am assuming you mean that their is no standard layout format. If you gave examples, I bet you would get even better responses

Answer (score 1):

Optical character recognition is a well-studied problem with many possible solutions ([ressources](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=optical%20character%20recognition&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&oq=)). CNNs have proven to work extremely well even for hand-written character recognition. Take a look at this two papers:

- [Backpropagation Applied to Handwritten zip code](http://yann.lecun.org/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-89e.pdf)
- [Comparaison of Classifier Methods: A Case Study in Handwritten Digit Recognition](http://yann.lecun.org/exdb/publis/pdf/bottou-94.pdf)

[Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners) is a beginner tutorial to do just that with Tensorflow.

If you need extra data to train your model, take a look at the [MNIST dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/).

Comment: How does this answer his question?

Answer (score 0):

One way could be applying a good segmentation technique  and then classifying all the regions with some algorithms  like(ann,svm,knn...), this method doesn't need a lot of training sample at all.
Another way is applying deep learning (but this would mean a lot of training samples) you could use a CNN which perform a regression and so as output it gives you the text(this would mean you have to set a max sentences length). But to avoid a max sentences' length you could use a CNN with also some RNN layers and then you feed the network with parts of the image(a cascade approach).